# Finding the canonical form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & -1 \\ -5 & 3 & 3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
I have to find two invertible matrices $P(2\times 2)$, $Q(3\times 3)$ such that $P^TAQ$ is a canonical matrix.

I know that the canonical form is 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
(from the lagrange method) but I have to find $P$ and $Q$.
I tried using matrix congruence though I don't understand how to do it when $A$ is not a square matrix $(2\times 3)$.

I'd be glad to get some help with this,
thanks.

Comment: Do you know what elementary transformations are?

Comment: Yes, and I think I have to use them. I know how with square matrices but not when n!=m (Anxm)

Comment: It's the same. Can you transform $A$ in its canonical form using elementary transformations?

Comment: Yes but when you use matrix congruence when you change a row you have to apply the same change to the same column, how can you do it when 2!=3 ?

Comment: Matrix congruence means something else to me. I don't know what you're talking about, but you don't need it. If you can transform $A$ in its canonical form, do it.

Answer (score 0):

What @GitGud is referring to in his comments is that if you find a series of elementary transforms $T_1,\cdots,T_n$ such that:

$$A\times T_1\times\cdots\times T_n=C$$ where $C$ is your canonical matrix.

Then by denoting $Q = T_1\times\cdots\times T_n$, you have:

$$AQ=C$$

Also, note that you have $\forall k\in[1,n], det(T_k)=1$ and thus $det(Q)=1\neq0$ which means $Q$ is invertible.

Now, let $P=I_2$ (i.e. $P$ is invertible and $P^T = I_2$) and you have:

$$P^TAQ=C$$

with $P\in M_{(2\times 2)}$ and $Q\in M_{(3\times 3)}$, both invertible.